# Flask Pagination without SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask

Looking to paginate the data set without using SQLAlchemy. Am getting the data from the database using query.

```
def data():
    cursor.execute("""select * from table_data""")
    records = cursor.fetchall()

    return reneder_template('data.html')
```

And am rendering this result in the @app.route method.

Pagination can be done using paginate and query method in SQLAlchemy, but since am getting the data directly from the database, suggestion will be helpful on pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below approach can be used to paginate in Flaks without using SQLAlchemy,

```
def data():

    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    limit=20
    offset = page*limit - limit
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select * from user_listing
                              table_data""")
    result = cursor.fetchall()

    total = len(result)
    print(total)

    cursor.execute("""select * from table_data
                        limit %s offset %s""", (limit, offset))
    data = cursor.fetchall()

    pagination = Pagination(page=page, page_per=limit, total=total)
    return render_template('data.html', pagination=pagination, data = data)
```

Reference - https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/